# Symfony2 "connection reset" only on one route

Tags: php, apache, symfony

I've been coding a project for some time. I'm quite new in Symfony2 and php frameworks, but find myself starting to understand it - which is great.

Now however something weird has happened, and I don't know where to start to look.

I was coding a scraper combining Symfony2 and casperjs - it has been working for some time and I was just dusting it off.

Suddenly I get a "connection reset" in Firefox. I try some other routes and they work fine. I try changing the route with a problem, but the same error pops up. I have tried the following:

- delete the caches
- isolating the casperjs part (works fine)
- restart the server
- restart apache
- checking apache logfiles
- checking symfony logfiles

But nothing of the above gives me any clues. Can the problem be with the virtual-host file when it is only a problem for a subpart of the site and not the site in general?

Any ideas is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Rune

Comment: Did you try to access your app in dev mode via /app_dev.php?

Comment: Yes - should have mentioned that - I only work in dev mode with /app_dev.php. I have tried with app.php. The issue is almost the same except it only shows a blank page and no "connection reset" error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the problem in my code.

I did not read the error-log of the project vhost properly.

For others with similar problems the error-log is a great place to start :)